# JSON formatting for API requests, lines only needed if value is given in Python

Tags: python, json, conditional-statements

I am working on a program that pushes API requests using command parameters from Python. My variables are held as follows:

```
parser.add_argument('--ilo', help = "iLO IP address for client")
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
ilo = args.ilo or "0"
```

For my JSON formatting, I have the following:

```
test = {
  "name": hostname,
  "device_type": type,
  "device_role": role,
  "tenant": tenant,
  "platform": platform,
  "serial": chassis_serial,
  "site": site,
  "location": location,
  "rack": rack,
  "position": position,
  "face": face,
  "status": status,
  "custom_fields": {
      "management_ip_address": f'{ilo}'
 }
}
```

This request in particular does not need all of these lines. Some variables such as 'ilo' and 'position' are not needed. Is there any way that I can make a conditional statement that if --variable is given then add the "variable": variable line to the JSON and if it's not then do nothing and don't add that line? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave those fields out initially, then add them in an `if` statement if needed.

```
test = {
  "name": hostname,
  "device_type": type,
  "device_role": role,
  "tenant": tenant,
  "platform": platform,
  "serial": chassis_serial,
  "site": site,
  "location": location,
  "rack": rack,
  "face": face,
  "status": status,
  "custom_fields": {}
}

if position:
    test['position'] = position
if ilo:
    test['custom_fields']['management_ip_address'] = str(ilo)
```